# Audacity Stop Record Freeze

Tags: freeze, ubuntu-studio, audacity

As the title reads, after recording audio, and pressing the stop button, audacity [freezes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VtjQzs_uv8). This doesn't appear to happen all the time, but when it does I terminate Audacity and then recover project upon reopening.

Help!

Comment: Try to start audacity from terminal with this command `export PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 && audacity` . Is still crashing ?

Comment: I'm under ubuntu 16.04 and got a similar problem. The LP record suddenly stop. Seems this command helps. Audacity became more stable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some general tips you may want to have a look at first. Make sure you have the latest version of Audacity, enough memory, etc.: 
http://theaudacitytopodcast.com/tap040-10-tips-for-how-to-keep-audacity-from-crashing/

If that doesn't help, look in to the known bugs for the current version of Audacity and see if anyone has found a workaround. This one seems similar to what you are experiencing, but maybe not exactly the same: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/audacity/+bug/792549

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me, too. Are you using qjackctl? If you are, there is a menu in the top left corner of Audacity. It will say ALSA. Change it to Jack Audio Connection kit and you should be good.  [image: Jack Audio Connection kit]